# how to launch pr2 simulation in jade

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorial of pr2 simulation:
http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/StartingPR2Simulation

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

this command is fine, the gazebo window shows an empty world. while run the following command :

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
```

an error occurs:

```
[pr2.launch] is neither a launch file in package [pr2_gazebo] nor is [pr2_gazebo] a launch file name
```

There's no package named 'pr2_gazebo' in jade, I tried to find it with apt-get:

```
aptitude search pr2
```

there are 6 packages in jade related to pr2:

```
ros-jade-pr2-common
ros-jade-pr2-dashboard-aggregator
ros-jade-pr2-description
ros-jade-pr2-machine
ros-jade-pr2-mechanism-msgs
ros-jade-pr2-msgs
```

none of them contains pr2.launch. So, how can I run simulation for pr2 in jade?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221746/how-to-launch-pr2-simulation-in-jade/) by [pitpet](https://answers.ros.org/users/24937/pitpet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-11-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitpet](https://answers.ros.org/users/24937/pitpet/) on 2015-11-30**:
why I can't see this question in the ask list? and it says 'this post is awaiting moderation', what does that mean? what do I need to do to moderate it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-30**:
@pitpet: as the question was posted by a new account, it has t go through the moderation process, which basically means that one of the ROS Answers moderators needs to ensure that you are not a bot that is trying to spam. I just did that, so your question should now show up on the main site.

**Comment by [pitpet](https://answers.ros.org/users/24937/pitpet/) on 2015-12-02**:
ok, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at [debbuild/jade.html?q=pr2](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/jade.html?q=pr2) and the [pr2_gazebo](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_gazebo) wiki page, it would seem the `pr2_gazebo` package (and many others in fact) have not yet been released for ROS Jade. The newest versions are for Indigo.

You might be able to build them from sources in a catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2